# Parent and Child relationship update

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have following data:

```
  ParentElem    ChildElem        Id                                 ParentElemId
  Core Sub      SDG-1       f2e3e594-92a7-44a5-9593-47381f29db10    NULL
  Core Sub      Rea 2       bfca0601-edbb-40aa-a360-f7381db888ef    NULL
  Core Sub      Rea 1       3c584b87-0f57-46c2-9819-eb103305e7f3    NULL
  Core Sub      PDM 3       c7b924b9-a93b-4db1-bd29-82b960ecb699    NULL
  Core Sub      PDM 2       4d0a3675-d526-4bea-86bc-d43678205dca    NULL
  Core Sub      Switchgear  41aba4f3-903f-4951-82d7-82093b004ffd2   NULL
  Distribution  Core Sub    5f528c32-87be-47b5-8e0f-6279d87dacf0    NULL
  Distribution  NPS         3b714bd2-69d8-4f43-95d8-10ce460325fc    NULL
  NPS           Switchgear  41aba4f3-903f-4951-82d7-82093b004ffd3   NULL
  Switchgear    BB1         d8aeabf0-f58f-4b79-b35b-3b8917eb41d1    NULL
  Switchgear    Interconnec d69ef085-c7ce-4129-90ef-00cfc4b92b6e    NULL
  Switchgear    Non-Busbar  93306313-996e-4d58-a978-7b91f2122ab0    NULL
  Switchgear    Panel 11    5ac4c79b-1673-4fc1-9a9a-a3697ae5c754    NULL
  Switchgear    BB2         f90ae7b4-d5f9-4047-b483-a41b0e2381cd    NULL
```

I'd like to get following:

```
ParentElem  ChildElem        Id                                 ParentElemId
  Core Sub      SDG-1       f2e3e594-92a7-44a5-9593-47381f29db10    NULL
  Core Sub      Rea 2       bfca0601-edbb-40aa-a360-f7381db888ef    NULL
  Core Sub      Rea 1       3c584b87-0f57-46c2-9819-eb103305e7f3    NULL
  Core Sub      PDM 3       c7b924b9-a93b-4db1-bd29-82b960ecb699    NULL
  Core Sub      PDM 2       4d0a3675-d526-4bea-86bc-d43678205dca    NULL
  Core Sub      Switchgear  41aba4f3-903f-4951-82d7-82093b004ffd2   5f528c32-87be-47b5-8e0f-6279d87dacf0
  Distribution  Core Sub    5f528c32-87be-47b5-8e0f-6279d87dacf0    NULL
  Distribution  NPS         3b714bd2-69d8-4f43-95d8-10ce460325fc    NULL
  NPS           Switchgear  41aba4f3-903f-4951-82d7-82093b004ffd3   3b714bd2-69d8-4f43-95d8-10ce460325fc
  Switchgear    BB1         d8aeabf0-f58f-4b79-b35b-3b8917eb41d1    NULL
  Switchgear    Interconnec d69ef085-c7ce-4129-90ef-00cfc4b92b6e    NULL
  Switchgear    Non-Busbar  93306313-996e-4d58-a978-7b91f2122ab0    NULL
  Switchgear    Panel 11    5ac4c79b-1673-4fc1-9a9a-a3697ae5c754    NULL
  Switchgear    BB2         f90ae7b4-d5f9-4047-b483-a41b0e2381cd    NULL
```

So as you can see, Switchgear is ChildElem of Core Sub and I need to set ParentElemId as Id from Core Sub which is ChildElem of Distribution.
The same for another Switchgear, which is ChildElem of NPS and I need to set ParentElemId as Id from NPS which is ChildElem of Distribution.
This is just example and rest of ParentElemId should be set with rule above.

I tried query below:

```
 update [Hierarchy2] set [ParentElemId] = (select Id from [Hierarchy2_copy] where
 [Hierarchy2].[ChildElem]=[Hierarchy2_Backup].[ParentElem])
```

but it complains to error below:

```
Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= 
or when the subquery is used as an expression.
The statement has been terminated.
```

Comment: CAn you explain the result set you're after here please? What is it your trying to achieve? normally, when dealing with hierarchical data in SQL Server, you either need to use an rCTE, or ensure you have a [`hierarchyid`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/hierarchyid-data-type-method-reference?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: I just need it to be ParentElemId filled out with proper ParentElem Id to use it in another application.

Comment: @Lamu: how I could apply rCTE for my example? Thanks!

Comment: Hi, is there any recommendations? Thanks

Comment: so there are only 2 child elements in that set that also act as parent elements;  As such the sub-query is pulling back two IDs and isn't sure which one you want to use.

Comment: @JoshGivens: the problem here is that I don't have Id for ParentElem next to Child Id but it exists as ChildElem and Id

Comment: @JoeGreen so you can limit it to where rownum = 1, or manually change them with the values you want.  Beyond that I'm not sure of any solutions, sorry.